# Question concerning all solutions of differential equation $(2+\cos t)y'+5y\sin t=10t(2+\cos t)^2y^{4/5}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

<s>I need to find ALL solutions of $$(2+\cos t)y'+5y\sin t=10(2+\cos t)^2y^{4/5}$$</s>

First of all, this is Bernoulli so we solve it according to known method. So after substitution $u=y^{1/5}$, I've obtained $u=c+10t+5\sin t+ln(\cos t+2)$ and $y=u^5$. Now I want to have all solutions. One which we obviosuly missed is solution $y=0$. So this is additional solution.

Now, If I am not mistaken, all of these solutions are not unique, because they all cross $y=0$ axis at some point, and when they do, they can, for example, move for a while on $y=0$ axis, and continue its road to infinity on different curve. Beside $y=0$ all solutions are unique.

Is it correct? And are these all possibilities?

EDIT

Sadely I've made several mistakes in this question and in my notebook.
First, properly written equation looks like:$$(2+\cos t)y'+5y\sin t=10t(2+\cos t)^2y^{4/5}$$

Idea of solutions is identical, but we obtain different result: $u=(t^2+d)(2+\cos t)$ and $y=u^5$. Now we have unique solutions whend $d>0$. Otherwise we have also solutions crossing $y=0$ and $y=0$, because we can take one path increasing to $y=0$, move on $y=0$ and than choose different curve leading to infinity. Are all solutions of these kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see how you have obtained your solution $u$. When you substitute $y=u^5$ and denote $\phi(x)=2+\cos x$ you get
$$
\phi 5u^4u'-5\phi'u^5=10\phi^2u^4
$$
which has a solution $u=0$ or, after cancelling with $5u^4$,
$$
\phi u'-\phi'u=2\phi^2\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \left(\frac{u}{\phi}\right)'=2.
$$
The latter has the solution $u(x)=\phi(x)(2x+c)$.

EDIT: The edited equation has similar solutions, which are $u_1=0$ or $u_2(t)=(t^2+d)\phi(t)$. Outside the line $y=0$ we have [the local uniqueness of the solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions), on the line $y=0$ we have two different solutions (if $d<0$) that you can switch between. In general, a solution can consist of (at most) five parts: first going down along $u_2$ until $y=0$ for a negative $t_1$ then continue a bit along $y=0$ to some other negative $t_2$, then go down/up along $u_2$ until the second cross with $y=0$ for symmetric positive $-t_2$, then along $y=0$ again and, finally, up with $u_2$ at some other positive $t$.

Comment: I am very sorry. I've made mistake when rewriting equation into my notebook and then here. I hope it is correct now.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk I have edited the answer.